# service not starting in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've installed nodepool in a virtualenv and I'm trying to start the service but it is failing as outlined below.  I had tweak a couple of things like copy in the referenced lib file.

It is my first time working with virtualenv so I'm probably missing something or have made a rookie error.  Can anyone assist?

cat /etc/systemd/system/nodepool-launcher.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Nodepool Launcher Service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
# Options to pass to nodepool-launcher.
Group=nodepool
User=nodepool
RuntimeDirectory=nodepool
ExecStart=/var/lib/nodepool/venv/bin/nodepool-launcher
Environment=PYTHONPATH=/var/lib/nodepool/venv/bin/python
Restart=on-failure
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/lib/nodepool/venv/lib64/python3.5
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/nodepool/venv

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

From /var/log/messages.

```
Dec 21 07:06:21 ca-o3lscizuul nodepool-launcher: /var/lib/nodepool/venv/bin/python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

ls -l /var/lib/nodepool/venv/lib64/python3.5/libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nodepool nodepool 67 Dec 21 06:56 /var/lib/nodepool/venv/lib64/python3.5/libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0 -> /opt/rh/rh-python35/root/usr/lib64/libpython3.5m.so.rh-python35-1.0
```

(venv)[nodepool@ca-o3lscizuul nodepool]$ tail -2 ~/.bashrc

```
source /opt/rh/rh-python35/enable
source /var/lib/nodepool/venv/bin/activate
```

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` refers to module locations, not the python executable. Try not setting it at all

Comment: Removed as suggest. Same error while trying to start service.

Comment: Also, don't set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` - IIUC the executables in the virtual env _should_ take care of setting up the environment needed

Comment: Yep, removed all that stuff.

Can get it starting as follows within the venv:

/var/lib/nodepool/venv/bin/nodepool-launcher -c /etc/nodepool/nodepool.yml

Comment: I changed ExecStart to the following and I no longer see the lib error but is still fails to start: ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'cd /var/lib/nodepool/venv && source /var/lib/nodepool/.bashrc && /var/lib/nodepool/venv/bin/python /var/lib/nodepool/venv/bin/nodepool-launcher -c /etc/nodepool/nodepool.yml'

Comment: So my issue now is that systemd cannot start the service.